# Receiving bytes with netcat

Tags: linux, netcat

I have a script that sends data over a TCP connection with netcat which is working well.

What I would like to do is receive the data sent back by the server, and on a specific response, do an action.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to extract the full data package sent to me.

For example, the server sends me the following data (caught on Wireshark):

```
02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00   ..........
31 00 03                        1..
```

but the output from netcat only prints '1' (0x31 in ASCII).

I would like to be able to print the full data packet `02 01 ... 00 03`. Is that possible?

Another problem is that each received data packet replaces the previous one. So even though I only currently can print the "1" from the received data, the next data will overwrite it in the output file.

Is there any way to add a new line to the output file after printing each received data packet?

I hope I have been clear enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to be able to print the full data packet 02 01 ... 00 03. Is that possible ?

For this I used the `netcat -o file` option. This dumps all traffic into the specified output file.